# Is "key" as an adjective, meaning "crucial", standard in American English?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, american-english, contemporary-english

As an adjective, *key* can mean "Of crucial importance" ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/key)).  For example: the *key facts* are the most important facts, or a *key worker* is an employee whose role is especially vital.

In British English, *key* in this sense is every bit as common and well-understood as *crucial* would be. There are some stock phrases where it's especially familiar, but it's not limited to those; you could put it in front of any noun (say, *key elephant*) and, with the right context, it would make perfect sense ("the matriarch is the key elephant to protect from poachers").

Many years ago, when I was a rookie, someone much more experienced told me that I shouldn't use *key* as an adjective because "Americans don't understand it".  I've been carrying that "fact" with me ever since then – and was just about to impart it to someone else the other day, when I paused to wonder whether it's actually true.

I can obviously see that the meaning is listed in American-centric dictionaries (e.g. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/key)), but that doesn't help me understand whether it's a common use or an obscure one.  I can't find anything about it in any online American style guide but, again, that might mean it's completely uncontroversial or it might mean it's utterly obscure.  And the fact the word *key* has so many different meanings makes it a difficult one just to Google for!

So, can anyone help please?

Comment: I'm not sure what references I can site (hence comment, not answer), but this born-and-raised American certainly thinks key=crucial is a common, everyday word.

Comment: As the other two key players point out, the answer is "sure", but it would be difficult to prove that!

Comment: @Joe do a corpus search to compare usage frequency. Lots of alternate meanings. Maybe search 'is key'?

Comment: The [Google Ngrams for "key player" / "crucial player" / "key factor" / "crucial factor"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=key+player%2Ccrucial+player%2Ckey+factor%2Ccrucial+factor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckey%20player%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrucial%20player%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckey%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrucial%20factor%3B%2Cc0) for the 'American English' corpus are very much like those for the English corpus.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for that analysis; it's the approach I was stumbling around looking for, and does seem to put the answer beyond any remaining doubt.

Comment: Ngrams are far from infallible/unmisinterpretable. But they're usually a lot better than opinions based on small skewed samples ('me an' mi mates').

Comment: Hi Mitch - for written English, for sure, and I'm always in admiration of folks on here who know how to use that technology.  For spoken English, it's a fascinating fact that it is possible the **best possible method, extant, in the whole world**, is to ask on this web site and get a few me-mates opinions. (Which is conceptually fascinating!)

Comment: It's worth noting the sentence fragment "the matriarch is the key elephant to protect from poachers" is IMO **a very poor use of key**, it doesn't fit with the usual, uh, usage scan of key.

Comment: @JoeBlow I've come to agree on that point, and perhaps it's what underpins the debate taking place in some of the answers, about whether **key** in this sense is genuinely an adjective or just part of a set number of phrasal nouns.  I was trying to demonstrate the former, but perhaps I've actually proved the latter.

Comment: FWIW, I suspect it would be easier to understand the meaning of *key* in this sense if it's understood to be related to the *key* in *keystone*.  Ie, it's a relatively small part but it holds everything else together, and things would fall apart without it.

Comment: Key to solving this riddle is to recognize that a key opens a lock. This is presumably the case for all English speakers, not just Yanks.

Answer (score 7):

It's a fair question, I suppose – I mean, I believe you were told what you said you were told. However, I'm having trouble imagining anyone on this side of the Atlantic who would be confused by this use of the word *key*.

As a matter of fact, sportswriters don't usually write for a sophisticated audience, but the *Boston Globe* wrote about:

> ***Three [key](https://www.bostonglobe.com/sports/2015/02/02/three-key-plays-that-won-super-bowl-for-patriots/jqhCun7pU1aUu2FVHsmAfL/story.html) plays that won the Super Bowl for Patriots***

and the *USA Today* published a story called:

> ***Gronkowski [key](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nfl/super/2015/02/01/rob-gronkowski-patriots-seahawks-super-bowl-xlix/22722465/) part of Patriots' winning Super Bowl***

More recently, a sportswriter analyzed Game 1 of the NBA Finals, saying:

> *Rebounding is a [key](http://www.cleveland.com/cavs/index.ssf/2015/06/lebron_james_assist_numbers_an.html) in any series in basketball, and that figures to be one of the biggest advantages for the Cavaliers. However, it was Golden State who won the battle on the glass, outrebounding Cleveland, 48-45*.

This isn't just a sports thing, either. From a recent New York Times interview with a publishing executive:

> *Every opportunity is a different challenge, and I will quickly assess what the [key](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/03/29/business/the-danger-of-one-size-fits-all.html?_r=0) issues are*...

In short, either your friend had an erroneous perception, or else he was pulling your leg.

Comment: For sure, Americans understand "key" as an adjective meaning "crucial." Perhaps what motivated that person to make that comment about Americans is that the British might use "key" in a wider range of contexts.  For example, "key elephant" is understandable but a little odd to my ear.  (I am a New Yorker.)

Comment: @StevenLittman Maybe I overreached with "key elephant" - on returning to the sentence, "understandable but a little odd" is a fair summary of how it reads to me as well. It sounds very much as though my erstwhile colleague was just plain wrong.

Comment: @Morton  Since I'm from New York and I've only been in England twice in my life, I wouldn't dream of suggesting I know everything they say over there.  Sometimes it sounds like wartime code. (I did have an English nanny for my kids, and I could understand her--summat).  But I can speak to what sounds right on the east coast of the US.

Comment: I generally interpret _key X_ to mean _crucial X_ – except for when I'm ordering [key lime pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_lime_pie).

Comment: @JR Believe it or not, "key lime pie" is a phrase I found genuinely confusing the first time I heard it (which wasn't all that long ago). That might be a lack of culinary knowledge rather than a British thing though.

Comment: @Morton: It's also true that for those of us Americans not from Florida, and thus not familiar with "Key limes" (which are named after the Florida Keys), the name doesn't make any sense unless its explained.

Comment: One of my grand-grand-uncles helped build alligator alley!

Comment: @PeterShor Huh. I had always just assumed that key lime pie was somehow named after the Florida Keys, though I'd never bothered to fact-check. I suppose there's just something inherently Floridian-sounding about it, somehow. (I'm a Rightpondian and so definitely do not have the excuse of being from anywhere near the Sunshine State…)

Answer (score 3):

"This is a key idea."

I learned as a child to use the expression above as a compound noun.  "Key" was not an adjective, but was part of a compound noun.  In recent years, I hear people saying

"This idea is key."

thus treating "key" as an adjective.

"This is the car key."

"Car" is not an adjective here, so you don't say "This key is car."   Likewise "key" as I first learned it.  Language changes even when we don't like it.

Comment: this is an outstanding point.  Actually could it be that **this new usage is rather AmE** !??

Comment: +1 for a valid argument. However, better to buttress every argument with something substantial, canonical, authoritative and easily accessible online. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

I am from and have always lived in the U.S. and I have always understood "key" as being sometimes synonymous with crucial. Of course, I have also steeped myself in British literature from a young age so that my experience might not be truly representative of the average american.  Interestingly enough, however, I ended up on this page because I was typing a paper and used key in that form, and Microsoft Word corrected me, saying that "key" could not be used in this way.

Comment: That's a comment. Not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I've lived in America almost my whole life and we say this all the time. You're good to go.

Comment: How long is your "whole life"?

Comment: I'm twenty. Out of the times when I was old enough to be a competent user of language, I spent a year and a half in Germany and about a year in Canada.

Comment: I've been here three times that long and I agree -- "key" as an adjective is understood by any halfway literate person.

Comment: -1 That's a useful comment. Not an answer.

Comment: @Kris *au contraire*, it answers the question(s) exactly. "Yeah, " (it's "standard" American English), "I've lived in America almost my whole life and we say this all the time." (evidence).

Answer (score 1):

I'm always astonished how tenacious the term adjective is for nouns that are part of a compond noun. I know that in English school books everything that is attributed to a noun is called adjective. A very dubious use, as adjective is a word class and no term for describing noun groups (with a noun as main element and all others things as subelements).

In the case of key term/key figure etc we have a special type of nouns, compound nouns. In "an old man" "old" is an adjective. In "raincoat" "rain" is no adjective and English grammar terminology should have a special term for describing the formation of compound nouns. I think it would be reasonable to say "rain" serves as compound element in "raincoat". To say it is an adjective is in my view a kindergarden term.

Comment: Well... in the abstract I'd agree, but that's what I was trying to get at with the (admittedly dubious) _key elephant_ example.  If they were simply accepted specific phrases, in the way that _raincoat_ is, you wouldn't be able just to make one up. Nor do I think we can just write it off as a noun performing the function of an adjective, because its meaning as an adjective is quite different from (although obviously linked to) its meanings as a noun.

Comment: As Michael Hardy points out, this is a word like "fun" that can be used either as an adnominal noun, or as an actual adjective (which can be shown by its ability to be used as a predicate for some people). I agree with the overall sentiment of the post wholeheartedly!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=key+element%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+key+element%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckey%20element%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckey%20element%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), it would appear that, up until about 1985, "key" in this sense was more common in US than in UK literature.  It's currently about 40% more popular in UK literature, though.

<sup>(I don't know how to embed the actual image, so someone is welcome to edit that in if they wish.)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Hope that helps.

Comment: See also: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=key+_NOUN_+element%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ckey+_NOUN_+element%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckey%20_NOUN_%20element%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckey%20_NOUN_%20element%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: [also key (*) target(s)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=key+target%2Ckey+targets%2Ckey+*+target%2Ckey+*+targets) may or may not say something about the emergence of this usage around the big war ...

Answer (score -3):

It is right, dictionaries label key also as adjective.The Free Dictionary has

- key decisions, the key element of the thesis; adjective, meaning of crucial importance, significant.

But I think such a label  is questionable as so often as to labels of word class in dictionaries.
key is no genuine adjective. You can't form comparative forms (key/keyer/keyest) and normally you don't use it predicatively (something is key).

I doubt that you often hear it in this latter use, and if so I would say such use is exceptional and I believe not standard.

"key" if used in adjective position as in "the key figure of the novel" keeps its character as a noun. It is used metaphorically, "the figure as important as the key to a door".

True, we can replace "key" by "crucial", but that does not mean that "key" has changed its word class. Labels of word class in dictionaries are to be considered with a critical eye. It is not rare that they lead astray.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/key

Comment: Even OALD lists key (something is key) as an adjective (without any restricting remark). I checked BNC to see how often is "...is key".  Only four instances. Seems to be en vogue with some speakers at the moment. Nevertheless I see it still as elliptic for  "something is of key importance".

Comment: So, say, "automotive" isn't a "genuine" adjective?

Answer (score -4):

The use of 'key' when pedants like me would use 'crucial' or even 'vital' is a blight furthered,in the main,by sportsmen and women on the media,radio,tv etc here in the U.K.It has now become the 'norm' and is used by the gen public on phone-ins,too busy or stupid to use 'crucial'.Notwithstanding its common use it is still grating to me,but then I am a snob.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Christopher Wren erred when he failed to call for a "crucialstone" at the top of the aches in his cathedrals.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, John. Wait till you earn the privilege to post comments. These guys here downvote comments posted as answers!

Comment: @HotLicks et al., Why vote someone below ground level?